# Help me with this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having difficulty getting the variable $t$ out of this equation

$$\alpha x  t + \beta  y  t + \gamma  z  t + \delta = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

We get:

$t(\alpha x+ \beta y + \gamma z)=- \delta$.

Hence:

$t= -\frac{\delta}{\alpha x+ \beta y + \gamma z}$,

if $\alpha x+ \beta y + \gamma z \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\alpha xt+\beta yt+\gamma zt+\delta&=0\\
t(\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z)+\delta&=0\tag{factorise out $t$}\\
t(\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z)&=-\delta\tag{subtract $\delta$}\\
t&=-\frac{\delta}{\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z}\tag{divide by $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z$}\end{align}

This is only valid when $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z\neq 0$ as otherwise the fraction is undefined